# File system structure in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm a iOS newbie, be gentle :)

I need to populate a table view with a file system like structure with folders and files. The structures depth is dynamic.

At the moment I reuse the same table view and reload it's data if a folder is selected to show the folders content.

How can I mimic a navigation controller like "view-switching-animation" when using a single table view ?

Is the single table view approach correct in this situation when the structure depth is unknown?

Comment: It's correct, but you can't really recreate that animation. Why not just push a new table view controller when entering a directory? That's how everybod does it.

Comment: Do you mean create a new table view controller in code and push that?

Comment: @digisense yes. Sort of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

As H2CO3 said, you're probably better going with the new VC, much simpler code.

OTOH, if you like hacking, here are a couple of ideas to try.

I've no idea if this will work, but you might have fun trying.

First option is try pushing yourself on the navigation controller stack.  If you change your data and do the push in the same function, this could work, unless the framework is being smart.

The second option is to wrap your tableView in a view, push the another VC with just a view inside it, and then transfer your tableview to the new view.  Your original VC is still retained, so there is no reason it't can't stay the delegate and datasource for the table.

It does feel pretty jacky, and I wouldn't want to be the one maintaining it, but it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the source code for a simple view and view controller that browses the iOS file system [here](https://bitbucket.org/nwoolls/filesystemview). This solution does not reuse the UITableView and instead pushes a new instance of the view controller onto the navigation stack.